# Change the visibility of shared element transition on transition listener events - android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I tried to change the visibility of the shared element (ImageView) in the transition listener. But the changes are applied only for a moment and then return to the original state.

In this case, I have a photo viewer activity that starts with an shared element transition animation and I want to make the shared element `GONE` after the animation is over. Then add a photo view fragment instead.

```
         window.getSharedElementEnterTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                if (!isBackPressed) {
                    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    addMediaFragment(uri);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

            }
        });
        window.getSharedElementReturnTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                removeMediaFragment();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use fade animation and add to your transition

```
Fade moreScene = new Fade();
moreScene.addTarget(R.id.activity_new_layout_img);
moreScene.setDuration(300);
moreTransitionSet.addTransition(moreScene);
```

Comment: I use an fade animation for the "window.setEnterTransition". However, I tried your solution but it did not work.

Comment: Do you use two xml pages for the transition?

Comment: I use a total of 3 xml pages. A `fade` for exit transition in calling activity and enter transition in called activity. A `circleToSquare`(custom) transition for shared element enter transition and a `squareToCircle`(custom) transition for shared element return transition in called activity.